# Unable to send email confirmation with FOSUSERBUNDLE

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a little problem sending the verification email with Symfony with FOSUSERBUNDLE.
When executing the command:

```
php bin/console make:registration-form
```

The prompt asks me the question if I want to send a confirmation email once the user is registered, I put yes and I finish the command correctly.  Registration files are well created with logic and template.  In the RegistrationController file I have identified the method for sending an email.

```
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
             
            $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('testtesttesttesttest@gmail.com', 'acme'))
                    ->to($user->getEmail())
                    ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            // return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_page');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

It is logically this method `sendEmailConfirmation()` that allows the sending of the verification email with the unique token :

```
 $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
                (new TemplatedEmail())
                    ->from(new Address('testtesttesttesttest@gmail.com', 'acme'))
                    ->to($user->getEmail())
                    ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                    ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
            );
```

However, I cannot receive the verification email in my SMTP host 'MailTrap'... Nothing happen after the created user even though I have the Mailer package and I have imported the line from my mail server:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://a9b22c1668:4687703a72@sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io:2525?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login
```

I tested sending an email with mailer via the terminal with `php bin/console mailer:test someone@example.com`
And I confirm that the email has been received in my MailTrap. As the emails are functional when I go through the shell, I started to look more in depth and in particular in the method:

```
sendEmailConfirmation()
```

Which leads me to the EmailVerifier.php file, and I can see that there are several anomalies in this file that my IDE underlines in red. I share with you a screen of the code it will be easier to understand:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUEl.png)

Is it normal ?
This is a feature that is supposed to work by default and i after having properly configured an smtp.

Thank for your help

I try hard many way to debug but that was impossible for me to find the correction.
I really need to send the verification mail to finish my auth.